# Can I create a Windows installer that can add the program path to the environment variables?

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables, installation

I have developed an application in Go that I want to create a Windows installer for. The problem is that it is a console app that would preferably be run with just a simple call from the Terminal/Cmd Prompt. For that I need to add the installation directory to the system environment variables. Is it possible to do this through a custom Windows installer of some sorts?
I already have the exe that I will want to be added to the system environment variables. I want it to be possible for the user to install the program wherever they want and then that the installer can add that directory to the environment variables. Is this possible?

Comment: With what technology are you developing your application please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this if you don’t do it now: [Visual Studio Create Installer Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286704/create-setup-msi-installer-in-visual-studio-2017)
I don’t know the exact possibilities of this myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wix Toolset, here is an example of how to add an environment variable:

- [Setting environment variables requires reboot on 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979741/setting-environment-variables-requires-reboot-on-64-bit)

Commercial installer authoring tools can also do this. For example, you can use the [free edition of Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html), you need to add your env var from [Environment Variables page](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/environment-variables.html), in the project you are creating.

I imagine others like InstallShield, etc. provide similar support (don't know in which of their editions)

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer*

Comment: Is it also possible to download the exe from the latest release page on github with Advanced Installer?

Comment: Do you mean, like an auto-updater? To inform the user a new version is available? If this is the question, the answer is yes (but you need to purchase one of the commercial editions, all include this feature). More details: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/auto-updater.html